# 提案された編集 レビューのエスカレーション

Tags: サポート, 編集, レビュー

[position:fixed;のaの階層を一番上にする方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/77836/46944)という質問記事に対し、質問本文の品質を上げるために編集を行いました。
私はまだ信用度が低いので、編集内容は「提案された編集」のレビューキューに入れられていると思われます。
[提案された編集へのリンク](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/29549)

現在、このレビューのステータスは

> あなたが提案した編集は、レビューの承認待ちです。

と表示されています。
編集から1週間ほど経過していますが、未だレビューの承認待ち状態です。

レビュー権限をお持ちの方々に対し、この編集のレビューをお願いしても良いのでしょうか？
承認でも却下でも、何らかの決定を下していただかないと私の編集が「コミュニティにとって歓迎される編集内容」かどうか判断がつきません。

レビューキューはスキップできるとのことなので、レビュー権限を持つ方の大部分がスキップされたのかな？とも考えています。そうであれば、この編集内容は永遠に承認待ちのままになってしまうのでしょうか。

コミュニティにふさわしくない編集内容なら却下で構わないので、何らかの形でレビューの確定を望んでいます。
よろしくお願いいたします。

##### 補足：編集内容

発生している問題をより可視しやすいよう、スニペット内のCSSに背景色と背景画像の修正を行いました。

- 問題が発生している要素の背景画像がデッドリンクになっているので、無料ダミー画像生成サイトのURLに差し替えを行った。
- 表示上上部にあるはずの問題要素が別の要素の下に潜ってしまう状態が視認しやすくするため、当該要素の背景色を追加した。元々のスタイルはtransparentで、潜っても視認しづらい状況だった。

Comment: 以前拝見しましたが、「無料ダミー画像生成サイトのURL」が質問を改善したかどうか or 改悪された/無意味かどうか判断がつかなかったので、自分はスキップしました。

Comment: [当該質問者の1つ前の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/77774/46944)でも同じ題材を扱っており、その際のスニペット内（スニペットも私がコメントで提示されたjsfiddleのコードを私が編集で移植したものです）に同じ無料ダミー画像生成サイトのURLで背景画像を作成していました。今回もそれと同様の記載になるように修正しました。※以前のコメントは削除しました。私見部分を削除して再投稿しています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

レビューキューに特に印が付いていなかったのでレビューできることに気付かず、先ほど承認のレビューをしました。

基本的にはウェルカムな編集だと思うのですが、以下の点において判断しづらい側面はあったかなと考えています。

- 差し替えられた画像が外部サービスを参照している点。

  - その外部サービスがリンク切れになってしまうと意味がなくなってしまいます。Stack Exchange では全サイト的に画像用のサービスとして imgur を使っているので、そちらへのリンクになっているとベターだったかなと考えます。ただし、別に外部サービスだったからといって表示される方がマシなので、却下の理由にはならないでしょう。
  - 「当該質問者の1つ前の質問でも同じ題材を扱っており、その際のスニペット内に同じ無料ダミー画像生成サイトのURLで背景画像を作成していました」とのことですが、この文脈は編集サマリーに無いため分かりませんでした。編集サマリーに何故この URL にしたかのメモもあって良かったかもしれません。
- 背景に色を足している点。

  - この「背景に色を足す」というのが、Q&A を分かりやすくすることに貢献しているのか、あるいは質問文の意図を変えてしまってはいないか、というのを判断するのに時間がかかりました。どちらかというと、回答の中でご自身の回答を分かりやすくするために使った方が話が早いかもしれません。

どちらの点もかなり細かいことなので、コミュニティの意見というよりかは私個人の感じ方だと解釈ください。繰り返しになりますが、編集の提案としては質問を改善する内容であったと考えています。

Comment: 当該編集が承認され、背景画像のURLがimgurになっていることも確認しました。今後スニペットに画像リンクを記載する際はimgurを利用するようにいたします。コードの編集をする場合は詳細に編集意図と解説を記載したほうが良いとのことですね。背景色を追加している件については、私の回答コードにも同様の背景色を追加しています。その対比として追加した意図は否めません。今思えばあまりよろしくない編集だったと思います（仰る通り質問文の修正コードも自分の回答に埋め込めばよかったかな？と。）貴重なご意見ありがとうございます。次回以降の投稿に活かしていきたいと思います。

Answer (score 3):

nekketsuuu さんの回答でほぼ言い尽くされていますが、敢えて補足すると…

- 「編集の提案」の承認 (または却下) には通常、**二人のレビュアー** によるレビューが必要です。今回リマインドしてくれた時点では、一人が承認、他のユーザーは何人かがスキップという状況の様でした。
- スタックオーバーフローで扱われる話題は広範囲に渡るので、すべてに精通している人というのは恐らく皆無です。レビューに挙がった提案の判断に自信が無ければ、適当に承認するよりは (スキップして) 別の詳しい人に任せる方が正しい行動だと思います。

  - ヘルプの内容を理解し、常識的な範囲で利用している分には気にする必要はありませんが、
    "良くないレビュー" が続いた場合にはレビューが [一時的に権限が停止される場合もあります](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/review-suspensions) 。

Comment: > レビューに挙がった提案の判断に自信が無ければ、適当に承認するよりは (スキップして) 別の詳しい人に任せる方が正しい行動だと思います。<-私もその通りだと思います。もしレビュー権限を持っていらっしゃる方が全員スキップしてしまったら当該編集の扱いはどうなるのでしょう。永遠にレビュー待ちになるのでしょうか。どちらにせよその場合は「コミュニティにそぐわない編集」であったと判断すれば良いのかなと考えています。ヘルプの内容は今一度理解に努めます。ありがとうございました。